# for loop in bash with multiple arrays

Tags: bash, loops

What I'm trying to do is like this:

```
for i in {{1..3}, {25..27}}
do
 echo $i
done
```

but it gives:

```
{1,
{2,
{3,
25}
26}
27}
```

I'm wondering how I can get a return as this:

```
1
2
3
25
26
27
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two ways. Drop the space after the comma or drop the entire outer brace expansion as unnecessary.

```
$ for i in {{1..3},{25..27}}
do
 echo $i
done

or

$ for i in {1..3} {25..27}
do
 echo $i
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't nest `{` and `}` and use it as:

```
for i in {1..3} {25..27}; do  echo $i; done
1
2
3
25
26
27
```